# Why do subvarieties correspond to Hodge classes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective variety and define
$$Hdg^k(X)=H^{2k}(X,\mathbb{Z})\cap H^{k,k}(X)$$
the group of integral $(k,k)$ cycles on $X$. Now it is a fact that we can 
associate to the complex subvariety of $X$ an element in $Hdg^{k}(X)$ but I don't quite get the details of the association. From what I have gathered so far I think we are working with the diagram

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{Z}_p(X) @>{i}>> H_{2n-2p}(X;\mathbb Z) @>{PD}>> H^{2p}(X;\mathbb Z)\\
@VVV   @. @VV{i}V \\
H^{2n-2p}_{dR}(X)^* @>{\cong}>> H^{2p}_{dR}(X) @>{de Rham}>> H^{2p}(X;\mathbb{C})
\end{CD}$$

Where along the top row we map
$$Z\mapsto [Z]\mapsto [Z]^{PD}$$
Where $^{PD}$ denotes the Poincare dual and $[Z]$ the pushforward of the fundamental class of $Z$ over the inclusion. Along the bottom row we map
$$Z\mapsto \left[\omega\mapsto \int_Zi^*\omega\right]\mapsto\left( \alpha \text{ s.t. } \int_{X}\beta\wedge \alpha=\int_Zi^*\beta\right)\mapsto \left(\alpha^{top} \text{ s.t. }\alpha^{top}(V)=\int_V\alpha\right)$$
(we assume that $Z$ is smooth and all that to make things easier). The last map is given by the inverse of the de Rham isomorphism.

Now the image of the bottom row can easily be shown to be a class of type $(p,p)$. The image of the top row is clearly the image of the integral cohomology class, by definition.

Now if this diagram commutes we have a map $Z_p(X)\to Hdg^p(X)$. However, I don't see why this diagram should commute. So my question is: why does the above diagram commute?

---

I'll add the following [link](https://books.google.nl/books?id=XrvzAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA149&lpg=PA149&dq=integral%20p,p%20class%20hodge&source=bl&ots=gmDbBK83lA&sig=DUhGn-Hg0yDAjYAao53aA04b_Ic&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf2PedivvMAhXC7RQKHZBXB5MQ6AEIKzAC#v=onepage&q=integral%20p%2Cp%20class%20hodge&f=false). At the bottom of page $148$ the authors states without proof (I renamed the objects to be consistent with the above):

> The canonical morphism $H_{2n-2}(X,\mathbb{Z})\to H^{2n-2p}(X,\mathbb{C})^*$ carries the topological class $[Z]$ of an analytic subspace $Z$ of codimension $p$ in $X$ into the fundamental class $\left[\omega\mapsto \int_Zi^*\omega\right]$.
>   Similarly, the morphism $H^{2p}(X,\mathbb{Z})\to H^{2p}(X,\mathbb{C})$ carries the topological class $[Z]^{PD}$ to $[\alpha^{top}]$

I am looking for a proof of this result. (this is equivalent with the diagram above commuting, but might give a bit more context)

Answer (score 2):

This is carried out in a lot of detail in Voisin – *Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry I*, section 11.1.2. The particular result you're interested in seems to be Corollary 11.15.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I'll look into it. I read some stuff by Voisin before, and so far it has always been really well written and clear, so I'm hopeful this will fix my problem.

Comment: Hm this does not seem to answer the question. The corrollary you state only shows that what I call $\alpha^{top}$ satisfies the condition I mention above. It doesn't say anything about the relation with the top row of the diagram.

Comment: I was under the impression that your main question was why subvarieties define Hodge classes. The commutativity of the diagram actually seems more related to a compatibility between the respective Poincaré duality theorems on algebraic de Rham cohomology, analytic de Rham cohomology, and singular cohomology. The comparison between PD on algebraic and analytic de Rham cohomology should follow from a version of GAGA, and the comparison between PD on de Rham and singular cohomology uses among other things a version of Stokes's theorem.

Comment: Sorry that my question wasn't clear. My question is indeed basically about compatibility between all the various maps between various (co)homology groups. The thing is that I'm looking for details, since no one seems to bother given them.

Comment: That's why I thought about Voisin in the first place: she gives the details for a different type of compatibility in Theorem 5.29. I didn't remember which thing she proved, but it turns out not to be what you want. Then I found the other chapter.

Comment: @user2520938, if that is your question, your choice of title is very very weird!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez well it not really my question. My question is stated in the body; why does the diagram commute? But of course the compatibility is strongly related to that.